# ¿Cómo autocompletar con jQuery UI en CodeIgniter?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, codeigniter, autocompletar, jquery-ui

Intento resolver cómo hacer el autocompletar con jQuery UI, no veo el error. ¿Me podrán ayudar? Veo en la consola que, si por ejemplo escribo código "333.." me aparecen los dos arreglos que empiezan con ese código, pero no los muestra en la vista.

Éste es mi controlador:

```
 public function getarticulos() {
        $q = trim($this->input->get('term'));    

        $productoresult = $this->articulo_model->find($q);
        $result = array();
        foreach ($productoresult as $i =>$articulo) {
            $result[$i]['id'] = $articulo->id;
            $result[$i]['codigo'] = $articulo->codigo;
            $result[$i]['descripcion'] = $articulo->descripcion;
            $result[$i]['precioactual'] = $articulo->precioactual;


        }          
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
```

Éste es el modelo:

```
public function find($q){

    return $this->db->query("select * from articulo where codigo like '%$q%'")->result();
}
```

Ésta es la vista:

```
 <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Sistema Stock</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/chosen.min.css" media="screen" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/mystyle.css" media="screen" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/jquery-ui.css" media="screen" />  
        <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
         <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  </head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {



        $("[name=codigo]").autocomplete({
            source: "<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/articulo/getarticulos",
            minLength: 3,
            select: function( event, ui ) {              
                if(ui.item.id){     
                    $("[name=codigo]").val(ui.item.codigo);                                   
                    return false;
                }
             },
            search: function (event, ui ){               
            $("[name=codigo]").val(0);
            }
        });

     });
</script>


<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-6"> 
        <div class='input-group'>
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag"></span></span>                
             <input id="txtcodigo" name="codigo" type="text" placeholder="Codigo" value="" class="form-control" required="">
        </div>
    </div> 

</div>
```

editado--
HICE UNOS CAMBIOS y ahora m muestra la lista, pero cuando selecciono, como tendría q ser? quiero q se guarde el valor del código y del id en los campos correspondientes,muestro como hice la función select: function( event, ui ) pero no devuelve el valor:

CAMBIE LA VISTA

```
$(function() {
    var cache = {};
    $( "#txtcodigo" ).autocomplete({
      minLength: 2,
          source: function( request, response ) {
            var menus = new Array();
            var term = request.term;
            if ( term in cache ) {
              response( cache[ term ] );
              return;
            }

            $.getJSON( "<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/articulo/getarticulos", request, function( result, status, xhr ) {
                  cache[ term ] = result;

            var count = result.length;
            console.log(result);
                    console.log(count);
                      for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                        menus[i] = { codigo: result[i].codigo, id: result[i].id, descripcion:result[i].descripcion};
                        console.log(menus[i]);
                         cache[ term ][i] = result[i].codigo;                    
                    }
              response(result);
            });

          },
           select: function( event, ui ) {               
                    $("#txtcodigo").val(ui.item.codigo); 
                     $("#txtid").val(ui.item.id);  
                        return false;

                 }         

        });
      });



    <label for="txtcodigo">Codigo: </label>
  <input id="txtcodigo">
    <label for="txtid">id: </label> 
  <input id="txtid">
```

Comment: Después de releer la pregunta y el código, voy a cambiar las etiquetas: el problema no tiene que ver con PHP o CodeIgniter (según @mer, los arreglos se reciben bien) ni con Bootstrap (no es un problema de estilos), sino con el `autocomplete` que es jQuery UI.

Comment: No relacionado con la pregunta en sí, pero sobre el código: **tiene problemas de inyección SQL**. No se sanea el valor que recibes de "term" y guardas en `$q`, y luego se usa en una consulta dinámica (no preparada). Deberías escapar o hacer bindings de esa variable (lee sobre esto en la [documentación de CodeIgniter](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html).

Comment: +1 Para el comentario de arriba. Esto es un error de seguridad gravísimo.

Comment: Hola, te agradezco por tu respuesta, pero no entendi bien cual seria la solucion :)

Comment: disculpen todavia no me manejo bien depurando, por ejemplo como hago para ver q valor toma 'term', como bien dije cuando utilizo las herramienta de desarrollo chrome puedo ver los arreglos  q necesito q se muestren, pero no se visualizan en la VISTA, APARECE VACIO

Comment: @mer asegúrate de que la URL es correcta en la vista y de que devuelve bien valores (puedes añadir `console.log` para verlos dentro de los métodos del autocomplete)

Answer (score 1):

Bueno creo que es porque te hace falta una llamada callback para hacer el autocomplete, en mi caso yo lo uso de esta manere

```
$("#myMenu").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        var menus = new Array();
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            type: "get",
            url: "tu_url.php",
            data: { "myMenu": request.term },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                var count = data.length;
                console.log(count);
                for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    //menus[i] = { label: data[i].alias, id: data[i].id_menu };
                    //console.log(menus[i]);
                    menus[i] = data[i].label;
                }
                response(data);
            }
        });
        //$.get(formMenu.attr('action'), { myMeny: request.term }, function (data) {
        //    console.log(data);
        //});
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        log( ui.item ?
      "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
      "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
    },
    open: function() {
        //$( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
    },
    close: function() {
        //$( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
    }
});
```

En donde esta claro que data:{"myMenu":request.term} es lo mismo que tu variable term y te quedaría algo como data:{"term": request.term} (lo que se lee en $this->input->get('term') en otras palabras)

Y por lo del saneamiento codeigniter ya esta preparado para ese tipo de cosas como [lo menciona la documentacion](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html) aunque no esta demas darle un toque extra a ello

Comment: La última frase no es del todo correcta. La página enlazada habla sobre cómo `input` ayuda con la prevención de XSS, pero no se menciona inyección SQL (que es el problema en el código de la pregunta). CodeIgniter ofrece opciones para [prevenir inyección SQL usando `escape()` o bindings](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html), pero OP no los usa. En esa misma página también se dice (en una caja de aviso) que aunque el Query Builder escapa lo mejor posible las tablas y campos, NO está diseñado para trabajar con cualquier cosa y recomienda NO pasarle datos no saneados.

Comment: Les agradezco su ayuda, pero sigo sin poder solucionar :( , lo malo q no m aparece ningun error, la lista m aparece vacia, pero en la consola si estan los datos q estoy buscando, si los trae de la base de datos

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro tiene toda la razon hermano, me falta mucho que recorrer :D seguire aprendiendo

Answer (score 1):

Es muy facil el autocompletado por medio de `base de datos`
primero que nada nuestro script con sus referencias de jquery ya anteriormente agregadas hacemos lo siguiente:

```
 $('#textinput').autocomplete({
        source: function(request,response){
            $.ajax({
                url:"http://pagina/controlador/getinfo",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data:{
                    valor: request.term

                },
                success: function(data){
                    response(data);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength:1,
        select:function(event, ui){
            data = ui.item.id;
            $('#id').val(data); //pasamos el ID del numero autocomplete seleccionado a un input hidden.
        },
    });
```

controlador:

```
public function getInfo(){
            $valor = $this->input->post('valor');
            $datos = $this->Modelo->getDatos($valor);
            echo json_encode($datos);
        }
```

Modelo:

```
public function getDatos($valor){
            $this->db->select('id,nombre as label');
            $this->db->from('tabla');
            $this->db->like('nombre',$valor);
            $result = $this->db->get();
            return $result->result_array();
        }
```

Con esto debería de funcionarte perfecto. Solo haz los cambios que se requieran para que funcione con tus datos.

```
Resultado:
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]